# How to increase pressure in a bottle?

Tags: pressure

Imagine a plastic bottle half full of water,
what are some cheap ways to increase pressure?
I'm trying to dissolve carbon dioxide in water, it doesn't happen very well at normal atmospheric pressure. I read online somewhere that you need 4 times normal atmospheric pressure (about ~60 psi) for carbon dioxide to really dissolve well in water. So I'm trying to increase the pressure in a water container.

What are some ways this can be achieved?

Comment: This seems like a list question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use electrolysis (two wires from a battery through a cork in the bottle - water will dissociate into oxygen and hydrogen, creating high pressure). However, beware: this is dangerous (as it is almost always the case with high pressure), as the bottle can explode and harm you or other people. Please be reasonable.

EDIT: And high pressure is not the only hazard in this case: the mixture of oxygen and hydrogen can explode if ignited.

Comment: if the water separates, carbon dioxide won't be able to dissolve in the nonexistent water!

Comment: @LukeAllen: You'll get more pressure than your bottle can handle well before you run out of water...

Comment: @Luke Allen: I concur with rodrigo's comment.

Answer (score 2):

are you filling the bottles with CO2? or regular air.    If your bottles are air tight, you could add a small bit of dry ice to each bottle then seal it tight and then refrigerate it, as CO2 absorbs better in colder water.

If you plan on drinking this, I'd do more research cause I'm not sure dry ice is safe for consumption - so check that out if this is a method to create home made soda or such.

Another method would be to add yeast and sugar and let the yeast add the CO2 and pressure as it eats the sugar - a plus with this approach is that it also creates Alcohol - and much fun was had by many.

Are you looking for more physical approaches?   Dissolved CO2 or dissolved air?   If the bottles are plastic and flexible, but also air tight, you could increase the pressure inside by cooling (but not freezing) the liquid inside, then sealing the bottle with colder denser air at the top.   You could also wrap the bottle tightly with bungee cords which wouldn't compress the water but would compress the air pocket in the bottle, at least a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could just apply external heat with the cap sealed tight

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest way will probably be to submerge the bottle.

Approximately for each 10 meters of water the pressure will increase 1 atmosphere. So your 4 atm will be reached at about 30 meters below the surface.

Just go to the sea, a deep river or even a big swimming pool, drag your bottle, tie a long cable to it and let it sink.

Comment: good idea, but I live too far from the sea in my case

Answer (score 0):

@LukeAllen, you don't just need to increase the pressure in your bottle.  If you increase the pressure as stated in some of the above responses, you will not be increasing the PARTIAL PRESSURE of carbon dioxide, so you will still have a difficult time dissolving carbon dioxide into the water in your bottle.

I have done exactly what you are trying to do.  To dissolve carbon dioxide in water the easiest way that I know of, get some dry ice.  Fill your bottle half way full of water and add several chips of dry ice.  Based on the ideal gas law, and the temperature and volume of the gas in your bottle (assume 0 deg C for temperature), you can get a close estimate for the mass of dry ice that will give you 60 psi.  When you have the dry ice added to the water, put the cap on the bottle and twist the cap tightly closed.  Place the bottle several feet away from anything that it can harm should it explode due to too much pressure.  Wait for approximately 30 minutes.  When you unscrew the cap, you will find that your water is fully carbonated.